# An alternative, distinct font for re-using i and j for indexes?

Tags: fonts, math-mode

I have used `i`, `j`, `k`, and `\ell` as indexing subscripts.

Now, I would like to write another equation with `i` and `j`, but keeping it clear that these are distinct indexes. I would prefer not to have to start going to more esoteric letters (as suggested in response to a [related question at math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/169658/9215))

Is there a font that will allow me to re-use `i` and `j` in two distinct equations?

Comment: Using primes might be a better choice typographically than using typeface distinctions...

Comment: `i,j,k` are also esoteric letters depending on the context. There is no standard for indices.

Comment: α, β, γ, ... are often seen as indices.

Comment: @Caramdir good idea, although in this case beta is the variable being indexed

Comment: I strongly urge you to use primes or other letters (even if they look esoteric to you).  It is very unlikely that you'll find two fonts whose lower case i's are different enough for a reader in a hurry (and there is no other kind) to easily see the difference between -- especially at subscript size.

Comment: @MarkMeckes thanks for the advise. I am on the hunt for an esoteric letter; I guess `\iota` is out, but `\gamma`, `\mathfrak{t}`, and `t` are on the current short-list

Comment: For what it's worth, personally I frequently use p and q, once i-n are all used up.

Answer (score 6):

The basic options are

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathrsfs,eufrak,bbold}

\begin{document}
    $i,\mathtt{i}, \mathbf{i}, \mathrm{i},\mathsf{i}, \mathfrak{i}, \mathbb{i}, \imath$
\end{document}
```

[image]

See also [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol)
*Table 213* in [`symbols-a4.pdf`](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) gives a good overview of those different math fonts.

Answer (score 2):

You can af course use `\mathbf{i}` or `\mathsf{i}`.

However, I would recommend you to use `\tilde{i}`, `i'` or similar to distinguish between different indices.